# Filtering noise in a data set

Tags: dataset, filter, spatio-temporal

I'm trying to filter out noise from a Sonar. The idea is that the sonar in aimed upwards, after an object has come in it's range, I want to be able to tell if the object is moving away or coming towards. Something very similar to that found in a car, except no beeping.
The problem is that the sonar readings come with noise and seeing that my car doesn't get crazy (suddenly getting a lower, or higher reading) - I believe I need to improve my filter. 
Currently I'm taking the median of 21 readings (I could go to about 40 readings), which time to time return garbage. What could be the other possible filter methods?

Comment: You should tell us more about the format of your signal.  The signal from the sonar will be not only a time series, it will also have readings from diferent directions, yes?  Then I guess you will need a filtering method also taking into account that spatial structure!